# Bit datatype in SystemVerilog

Tags: memory-management, types, system-verilog

```
  bit id_pkt ;
  id_pkt++ ;
```

I found this code snippet while learning some aspects of SV. Now, isn't 'bit' a 2 state data type? So technically it should only take either 0 or 1 right? How can you keep incrementing a variable of bit datatype? Or is it that a bit type variable has some default 32 bits allocated to it? And so this is also a valid bit variable -> 110000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a single bit can only take on the values 0 and 1. So `id_pky++` toggles the value from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
module testthebit ;
 initial begin
   bit wr_rd ;

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
  begin 
    $display(" The value of wr_rd is %0h",wr_rd) ;
    wr_rd++ ;

  end
 end

endmodule
```

Yeah, so I wrote this module, and the results were like you predicted @dave_59 :-

The value of wr_rd is 0

The value of wr_rd is 1

The value of wr_rd is 0

The value of wr_rd is 1

The value of wr_rd is 0

The value of wr_rd is 1

The value of wr_rd is 0

The value of wr_rd is 1

The value of wr_rd is 0

The value of wr_rd is 1